# Is there a script to auto apps on my new distro?

Tags: autorun

I'm building an ubuntu 18.04 distro and i want to have some autorun apps.
Is there a way of doing this so that when i build and install my new distro, those apps/settings will be recorded and do the autorun by default from the settings i made on my "old" distro?
i think some conf file can be made right?

for example, wireshark is autorunning on my actual distro, and i want to "copy" this settings to the new distro

Comment: sorry for the confusion. this is a project to manage networks for school. at log in theres no dificult to do that. i need autorun at boot and those settings has to implemented on my new build, so that when someone install it, apps will be autorunning by default

Comment: SYSTEMD it's what i need